# Issue with relative path

Tags: coveo

Good day,

I have a issue when my page is loading. The normal behaviour is that all javascripts files are loaded in the request url: http://example.com/Coveo/Hive/js/Searchbox.min.js .

But sometimes the javascript load in the request url: http://example.com/Searchbox.min.js , so here i have the issue because that resource in the path doesn´t exist.

I don´t find a solution, does anyone know about this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you render that link?

Comment: Which Coveo for Sitecore version? Are you using the Coveo for Sitecore Hive framework or the legacy (WebForms or MVC-tagged) components? Is lazy loading enabled?

Comment: Hi @flguillemette
Sitecore version: 8.2.170728
Coveo for Sitecore is the version: 4.1.184.19
I am using the Coveo for Sitecore Hive Framework. 
Lazy loading is enable.

Answer (score 1):

This issue related to lazy loading, and the way the Coveo JavaScript Search Framework detects what is the path to use to lazy load its components.

This issue was fixed in `4.1.414` by adding `class="coveo-script"` directly on the script that loads the Coveo JavaScript Search Framework.

In the `Views/Coveo Hive/Resources/Coveo Search Resources.cshtml` file, the line

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src='@(Html.Coveo().IsEditingInPageEditor() ? Model.Properties.CoveoSearchUiPath + "/js/CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.js" : Model.Properties.CoveoSearchUiPath + "/js/CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.min.js")'></script>
```

should now read:

```xml
<script class="coveo-script" type="text/javascript" src='@(Html.Coveo().IsEditingInPageEditor() ? Model.Properties.CoveoSearchUiPath + "/js/CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.js" : Model.Properties.CoveoSearchUiPath + "/js/CoveoJsSearch.Lazy.min.js")'></script>
```

Adding this tag will make it so the lazy loading path is properly detected, and will properly load the components.

I would recommend upgrading to at least `4.1.414` since it contains the fix that you need.